# Select fields which contain all values of input array

Tags: mysql

So I have an array:

```
$someArray => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 7
    )
```

and I have MySQL fields:

```
+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
| 1,2,3,4 |
+---------+

+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
| 1,3,5,7 |
+---------+

+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
| 1,8,7,6 |
+---------+
```

Is there a way to write a query that would return only the third field (because that one has 1, 6 and 7 in it's value field)? I know I can use FIND_IN_SET three times, but I'm hoping for a more robust solution.

Thanks

Comment: relational division anyone?

Comment: why are you storing comma separated value?

Comment: That's the given DB architecture

Answer (score 1):

You should concat your query as follows using some loop on your array...

```
FIND_IN_SET(1,`column_name`) AND FIND_IN_SET(6,`column_name`) AND FIND_IN_SET(7,`column_name`)
```

Hoping I got your problem correct

Comment: yup that's what I planned to do, but I was thinking maybe there was something similar to array_intersect in PHP..